# Degree of Adjective usage with 'comparatively'

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Between 'The weather is comparatively hot today.' and 'The weather is comparatively hotter today', which is correct ? Also, what about 'The weather is comparatively hot/hotter than yesterday.'?

Answer (score 0):

Using "hotter" already implies a comparison, and saying "comparatively hotter" is incorrect. To say that the weather is comparatively hot is to say that it is moderately hot compared to something, though the "something" needs to found from the context. After several 15 degree spring days a 25 degree day would be noted as "comparatively hot", while after several 40 degree days it would be noted as "comparatively cool".

Generally "comparatively hot" is not as hot as just "hot". The word can be used to suggest something is not really hot, it just appears hot in the context.

"Comparatively" is normally used with adjectives that are not extreme, so warm or cool, hot or cold, but not boiling or freezing. "Comparatively boiling" would only be used as a joke.

Comment: The weather is comparatively hotter [than some other time implied time period.]